# RegEx - Match URL with/without slash at end

Tags: javascript, regex, string, google-analytics-api, pcre

How to have a regex matching:

`chocolate-pudding/ice-cream`

`chocolate-pudding/ice-cream/cake`

But not matching:

`chocolate-pudding/ice-cream-foo-bar`

Comment: `/chocolate-pudding\/ice-cream(\/|$)/`

Comment: @JaromandaX so close.. although does not capture the base string see https://regexr.com/3r5rp

Comment: if you test **one at a time** it works without any extra flags ... if you want to test a multiline string and see what is matched, you'll need both `g` and `m` flags - so, it's not "so close" ... it's ***exactly 100% correct*** - because in the question, all three paths are obviously separate, and not one multiline string

Comment: What is your current regex?

Comment: can you explain what you want? is it anything after ice-cream or is it anything with two words

Comment: actually your original answer works! just had the wrong regex format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive positive lookahead for either whitespace or forward slash character.

```
(chocolate-pudding\/)(\w*-\w*)(?=[\s\/])(\/?\w*)
```

Live regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/8WMKuI/2).